# Reputation graph doesn't scale well for negative scores

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph

I recently posted a bounty for 500 reputation, but the graph only shows a red bar of magnitude 50. This makes it appear approximately equal in size to (say) June 13 when I gained 60 rep. The same is true in the minimap: the red bar is about the same magnitude as the nearby green bar. This really throws off the scale of reputation changes and makes it difficult to get a sense of when large negative reputation was incurred.

It would be nice if the scale adjusted so that my -500 reputation doesn't look the same as a -50, and so that it doesn't appear that -500 is offset by a +60.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know this is [status-bydesign].

Comment: ^ It would make sense, since developers don't want you to know about negative changes to your reputation.

Comment: @TylerH Err, who are "developers" and why don't they want me to know about my own rep?

Comment: @Eric Stack Overflow employees/developers who write the code that runs the site. I don't know why, but there are a number of by-design 'features' that mitigate your ability to see and be notified of negative rep changes when compared to the notification and visibility of positive rep changes. When pressed on this, the message is usually that it's by design.

Comment: Related: [Bounties can make the profile reputation graph look silly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109139/bounties-can-make-the-profile-reputation-graph-look-silly)

Comment: @Floem Thanks for finding that! I'm confused though: it is [tag:status-declined].

Comment: I don't mind the idea of clipping the anomalous reputation events (-500) so that the other normal days (+25, +60) are still readable and not squished together.  I just wish they also clipped the positive anomalies as well for the same reason.  So if you had instead earned +500 bounty, it would resize the entire graph and squish the normal days out.  For example, check [Gordon's reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=reputation) from Sep to Oct 2014.